# Click function not called when table column is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, jquery-selectors

I can't figure out why the click function within my JavaScript won't work. I am creating a table based on values in a JSON file, and I am assigning classes to the table columns.

Here is the structure of the HTML once it's added from the JavaScript:

[image: html table structure]

```
$(function(){
  //Code that adds table goes here

  $('#plane td.availableSeat').click(function() {
    console.log('Clicked');
    $(this).className = 'selectedSeat';
  });
});
```

The click function never seems to be called, even though I (think) the selector is correct?

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is all your jquery inside a `$(document).ready() {}`?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here your code works. https://jsfiddle.net/pnz4re7w/

Just make sure your `$('#plane td.availableSeat').click` is called AFTER you populate the table from the said JSON.

Right now it looks like that you're assigning the click event on load, and then the tables is populated.

Comment: The click code is definitely after the code for creating the table within `$(function()`. The table is created at the point where I have the comment...

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        table tr td {
            border:dotted 2px red;
        }
        .selectedSeat {
        color:blue;
        }
    </style>
<script>



    $(document).ready(function () {
        var szTr='<tr>';
        szTr=szTr+'<td class="availableSeat">availableSeat</td>';
        szTr=szTr+'<td class="unavailableSeat">unavailableSeat</td>';
        szTr=szTr+'<td class="availableSeat">availableSeat</td>';
        szTr=szTr+'<td class="unavailableSeat">unavailableSeat</td>';
        szTr=szTr+'<td class="spacer">spacer</td>';
        szTr=szTr+'<td class="availableSeat">availableSeat</td>';
        szTr = szTr + '</tr>';
        $('table').append(szTr)

    $('#plane').find('td.availableSeat').click(function () {
        alert('Clicked');
        $(this).addClass('selectedSeat');
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body style="width:50%;">
  <div id="plane">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="availableSeat">availableSeat</td>
            <td class="unavailableSeat">unavailableSeat</td>
            <td class="availableSeat">availableSeat</td>
            <td class="unavailableSeat">unavailableSeat</td>
            <td class="spacer">spacer</td>
            <td class="availableSeat">availableSeat</td>
        </tr>

        </table>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work for dynamically added elements. You must use [jQuery's delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function in this case, which attaches the event to some parent of the element and hence allows event triggering for the dynamically added child elements. Your code for click event handler needs to be like this:

```
$("#plane").delegate("td.availableSeat", "click", function() {
    alert('Clicked');
    $(this).className = 'selectedSeat';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the current class and then add the new class
    $(this).removeClass('availableSeat');
    $(this).addClass('selectedSeat');

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't get any of the suggestions to work, however I managed to find a solution.

I added `cell.onclick = updateSeatStatus;` to the creation of each `td` element, and created this function:

```
function updateSeatStatus() {
   this.className="selectedSeat";
}
```

Works exactly as intended.